# How to update status value in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

In my database i had table with "tblstatus" and "tblemployeereimbursmenttable".

here status are in this format

> 1 Pending with employee
>       2 Pending with Manager
>       3 Send back by Manager
>       4 Pending with Finance
>       5 Send back by Finance
>       6 Pending with Account head
>       7 Send back by Account head
>       8 Approved

And Given PK and FK relationship to two tables
Here when the button clicked than status update to 2 in gridview.

```
if(Session["statusID"] == 1)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))// set ConnectionString
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update from table set statusID=2 where      expenesesid=@expensesid",con)) // set appropriate query
        {
            sqldatadapter da=new sqldatadapter(cmd) ;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

But it's showing error can any one help me please....

Comment: ya while update it's showing error in   if(Session["statusID"] == 1)----here(in this line)

Comment: select Session["statusID"] and apply add watch to it and debug the code. and check what u r getting.

Comment: BTW what kind of error you are getting??? Please mention the message you are getting as an error..

Comment: ya here i found the error that conversion problem but,update value is not updating when burton clicked ,status column should update but not.

Comment: you haven't assigned any value to @expensesid....

Comment: no here @expensesid column having primary key

Comment: but if u not give value to it how it's gonna update the value ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast session data:

> the type of an item stored in the session is Object; you always need
>   to cast it to its actual type when you retrieve it.

```
int statusID =0;

if(Session["statusID"] != null && int.TryParse(Session["statusID"].ToString(), out statusID) && statusID ==1)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))// set ConnectionString
    {
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblstatus set statusID=2 where      expenesesid=@expensesid",con)) // set appropriate query
        {
            sqldatadapter da=new sqldatadapter(cmd) ;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,here is the error      'int.TryParse(string,out int)' has some invalid arguments ---error

Comment: Sorry, dropped `()` from `ToString()`. Fixed now.

Comment: i dont why no error but  value is not updating .here expensesid column having primary key.i didn't wrote any stored procedure,so need to mention in code?

Comment: I guess Session["statusID"] is null... can you debug at this point to see what is in Session["statusID"]?

Comment: no here i kept default value for sessionId=1 using sql query  ,no null value stored in db for statusid column

Comment: Another error... replace `update table set... ` with `update tblstatus set statusID=2`

Comment: Set a break point here and see if it executes at all : `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: hi can ou please check your mail i had forword my project to your mailid:afzalulhb@gmail.com

Comment: Okay, I'm looking at it.

Comment: while copying log file it's giving error .if you want db details i will tell you

Comment: You are missing a line after this: `update tbl_Status set StatusID= 2 where ExpensesID=@ExpensesID`. You should have something like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@ExpensesID, YourExpensesID);` Here YourExpensesID is the ID of the record you will update.

Comment: here how can i give dynamic value for ExpensesID,here i am not using any textbox for that how?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40896/discussion-between-afzalulh-and-sandeep)